# Where is the file size limit stored in the system tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have many databases restored from various other database servers on a shiny new server. I want to unify the log file size limits and allocation percentages. However, I'd like to not do this by hand so we can conform things as time passes.

Comment: What database software are you using? MS SQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to set size limits on the transaction log files.  If you do and a log file fills the users won't be able to use the application any more until to resolve the issue.  Set all the transaction logs to grow to what ever size that they need, and don't shrink them unless a rogue transaction comes through and grows the log larger than is normally needed.

If space becomes an issue, buy more drive space.

Comment: Should be rogue, not rouge. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Someday I'll learn to spell above a 4th grade level.  Apparently today is not that day.

Comment: Eh, we all have those days.

Comment: This may not be the best advice for you. When you have 20 DBs on a server, you don't want one filling up shared drive space for logs and ensuring that more than one DB goes down before you can get in there. If your usage is predictable, you go right ahead and set intelligent limits so that one runaway DB doesn't take the whole server down.

Comment: This is a fine answer, and I agree with you, however, they were all set to 20mb, and I have databases failing and I need to bring the limit up for all of them

Answer (score 1):

Short:

```
-- within a DB context
use [DBxxx]
select * from sys.database_files

-- all files on the DB
SELECT * FROM master.sys.master_files
```

You want to read up on this more before sizing your TLogs. Check out Kim and Paul's articles on SQLSkills.com.

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/Transaction-Log-VLFs-too-many-or-too-few.aspx

You're almost always better off with a growth size that isn't a percentage. And unless you have a dedicated drive for the only important Tlog in your system a limit may save you from a wider outage. More importantly, after killing a rogue process having a bit more TLog space to allow may let you get the rollback started or an emergency TLog backup completed without out having to go down to do it.